# Unhandled Exception when trying to save data in Win Mobile 8 c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, storage, application-data

I'm using the code below to try and save to the local setting in Windows Mobile 8 using c#.

```
 public void SaveInfo(string key, string value)
        {
            if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[key].ToString() != null)
                {
                    // do update
                    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[key] = value;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                // do create key and save value, first time only.
                ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.CreateContainer(key, ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
                if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[key] == null)
                {
                    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

When calling the code the debug crashes with the exception below:

> *An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll*

Any idea

Comment: can you attach a debugger and see where the exception is happening? Nearly impossible to tell what is going wrong here based on the information posted (too many possible sources of exceptions here)

Comment: it occurs on the first call:

Comment: if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey(key))

Comment: What do you pass in as key?

Comment: To try and save the info I use 

SaveInfo("mcsserver", urlText.Text);

urlText being the TextBox containing the info I need saving to a key called "mcsserver"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the `IsolatedStorageSettings` feature, as below:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;


            settings["test"] = urlText.Text;
            settings.Save();
```

Comment: Your code is redundant. In other words. It does the same thing no matter what. If the dictionary does not contain the key, it adds the key, it is does, it overrides the key. In either case, the dictionary has the key and value. Simplify your code by not checking if it contains the key and simply do `settings["test"] = urlText.Text;`

Comment: Thanks for the tip Shawn, I Was just using code from another example

Comment: The key takeaway if the code as in this answer is slower. With the code you posted, the dictionary needs to do two hash lookups. When only setting via the index `settings["test"] = urlText.Text` it only has to do one hash lookup. 90% of the time two hash lookups are not noticeable. But if you are doing a lot of work with a dictionary (inserting thousands/millions of records), this can become costly.